# Equality of the power set to its cardinal number ($|\mathfrak P(M)|$ = $2^{|M|}$), Proof for Greenhorns

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory

Ok, here is my simple-to-understand proof without too much mathematical gobbledygook that $|\mathfrak P(M)|$ = $2^{|M|}$.

Proof:

First we construct for an arbitrary subset B of a set M a function $f_B: M \to \{0,1\} $ with the rule that $f_B(x) = 1$ iff $x \in B$, else $f_B(x) = 0$. So $f_B$ codes precisely and only the subset B from M.

Next we construct another function $F: \mathfrak P(A) \to M_{\{0,1\}}$ with $f_B$ connecting to $B \in \mathfrak P(A)$, so every $B \in \mathfrak P(A)$ gets only its characteristic function $f_B$ out of $M_{\{0,1\}}$. Therefore F is injective („only“) and surjective („every“). Therefore F is bijective, i.e.$|\mathfrak P(M)|$ = $|M_{0,1}| = 2^{|M|}$. $\square$

Could you check if it is correct though of course it will not have the precision of a more formal proof.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The standard proof doesn't just construct a bijection, of course, it **also verifies** that the claimed bijection is actually a bijection. Specifically, we define $$f:\mathfrak{P}(A)\rightarrow 2^A: X\mapsto\lambda x.\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if }x\in A\\ 0 & \mbox{ if }x\not\in A\\ \end{cases}$$ and then prove that this $f$ is both injective and surjective. What part of this is not compelling?

Comment: I always only see  just what you have written down. How does it prove that f is injective and surjective? Obviously it is trivial for you guys but I do not „see“ it. I would need an additional subproof why this function must be injective and surjective. Could you maybe give it?

Comment: For injectivity, suppose $X,Y\subseteq A$ with $f(X)=f(Y)$. Then by definition of $f$, for all $a\in A$ we have $a\in X\iff a\in Y$. So $X=Y$. For surjectivity, given $h\in 2^A$ consider $\{a\in A: h(a)=1\}$. Is any of this unclear?

Comment: and this is the first time I am hearing of 'brute contradiction'!

Comment: I've never heard of "brute contradiction" before either, I think I'll use it sometime ;)

Comment: @Noah I changed my question and tried an easy-to-understand proof. Is this a version that could be called a proof like in a textbook for real beginners in set theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, I will critique your proof. In fact, I find it hard-to-understand and full of "gobbledygook" - not to mention incomplete.

The first paragraph is fine, except that the sentence "So $f_B$ codes precisely and only the subset $B$ from $M$" is unnecessary and could be omitted. In the second paragraph, I have many comments:

1. What is $A$? When you wrote $\mathfrak{P}(A)$, did you mean $\mathfrak{P}(M)$?
2. What is $M_{\{0,1\}}$? I presume you meant the set of functions $M\to \{0,1\}$. This is usually denoted $2^M$, or $\{0,1\}^M$, or less commonly: $^M\{0,1\}$. I guess this last notation is what you meant. Note that it is the $M$ in a superscript, not $\{0,1\}$ in a subscript.
3. You write "we construct another function $F$...with $f_B$ connecting to $B$". Did you mean to define $F(B) = f_B$? It would be much clearer to just write this definition.
4. Most crucially, you have not actually checked injectivity and surjectivity. Your function $F$ maps from $\mathfrak{P}(M)$ to $2^M$, so the fact that *every* input set $B\in \mathfrak{P}(M)$ maps to a *unique* output function $F(B) = f_B$ only verifies that $F$ is a function. To prove that $F$ is a bijection, you need to show that for *every* function $g\in 2^M$, there is a *unique* set $C\in \mathfrak{P}(M)$ such that $F(C) = g$.

---

Here is how I would write the proof in detail.

For every subset $X\subseteq M$, we have a characteristic function $1_X\colon M\to 2$, defined by: $$1_X(m) = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if $m\in X$}\\ 0&\text{if $m\notin X$}.
\end{cases}$$

We define a function $F\colon \mathcal{P}(M)\to 2^M$ by $F(X) = 1_X$.

$F$ is injective: Suppose $X,Y\in \mathcal{P}(M)$ with $F(X) = F(Y)$, so $1_X = 1_Y$. Then for all $m\in M$, $1_X(m) = 1_Y(m)$, so $m\in X$ if and only if $m\in Y$. Thus $X = Y$.

$F$ is surjective: Suppose $g\in 2^M$. Let $X = \{m\in M\mid g(m) = 1\}$. I claim that $F(X) = 1_X = g$. To show $1_X = g$, we show that they agree on all elements of $M$. So let $m\in M$. If $g(m) = 1$, then $m\in X$, so $1_X(m) = 1$. If $g(m) = 0$, then $m\notin X$, so $1_X(m) = 0$.

Comment: I am so thankful to you. I understand this finally because your proof is step-by-step, not like those proofs in many books that are very reduced, so only pro mathematicians can grasp it.